# Custom NSControl classes in OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to develop a new custom NSControl. All of the guides and examples I can find (including [Apple's Subclassing NSControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/Tasks/SubclassingNSControl.html) article) are built around NSCell. But as of 10.10, all of the cell-related messages on NSControl have been deprecated.

I tried just creating a subclass and adding to my project via a custom view in IB, but I can't get the control to accept first responder despite being enabled, setting refusesFirstResponder to NO, and return YES from acceptsFirstResponder. And I'm sure I'm missing a lot of functionality (value change notifications, etc.) that are supposed to be there.

Is there are newer reference around that shows how controls are now supposed to be developed? My Google-fu is letting me down if there is. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm trying to deal with the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: No, never did—I set it aside to work on something else and haven't gotten back to it yet.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem likely was that you never actually set the control to be first responder. Simply clicking on it won't do it automatically. Below is a quick example which accepts first responder status (and becomes so on click too), and draws a focus ring. Be sure to enable the control and set its target and action.

```
class MyControl: NSControl {


    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }


    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }


    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        window?.makeFirstResponder(self)
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        if let action = action {
            NSApp.sendAction(action, to: target, from: self)
        }
    }


    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        NSColor.white.set()
        NSBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: 1, dy: 1), xRadius: 3, yRadius: 3).fill()

        if window?.firstResponder == self {
            NSColor.keyboardFocusIndicatorColor.set()
        } else {
            NSColor.black.set()
        }
        NSBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: 1, dy: 1), xRadius: 3, yRadius: 3).stroke()
    }


    override var focusRingMaskBounds: NSRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 1, dy: 1)
    }


    override func drawFocusRingMask() {
        NSBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: 1, dy: 1), xRadius: 3, yRadius: 3).fill()
    }

}
```

Comment: My question regarding a modern reference for subclassing NSControl still stands; if Apple has released an updated article I haven't stumbled across it yet. As far as first responder: I left that code and took a different approach, and it was too long ago for me to remember.

Comment: If you exclude NSCell, building controls is *much simpler*. Controls aren't really any different than any other view that handles user input events. The only thing in the past that separated them was their use of NSCell as the primary mechanism for events and display, so that they would work in table views etc. Now that NSCell is dead, it's simple — just use what's available in NSView/NSResponder/NSControl APIs. I'm not sure what a new guide would really offer.