# NSTableCellView Focus Ring

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, tabbing

I am trying my best to figure out how to add accessibility and tab management for my app, but I am struggling with those TableCellViews.

Context: I have a list of items, 1 column, 1 cell per row. I want to make the app usable using tab management, so basically, just use the tab to go up and down in the list and press space to select an item.

I managed to make the cell the firstResponder (in a dumb way..), but it won't show the focus ring, and when I press space it won't select the item.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What views are in the cell, one `NSTextField`? Is the text field editable? What should go up and down in the list, the selected row or the focused text field? What is "select the item"? Post your code please.

Comment: Has to be enabled and editable to have focus ring. Focus ring means the control is able to receive key events/keyboard events.

Comment: @Willeke a button and an image, but i want the cell itself to be the one in the focus ring

Comment: Maybe this helps [Custom NSControl classes in OS X 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323132/custom-nscontrol-classes-in-os-x-10-10)

Comment: What if [Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204434) is switched on?